# How to create a tooltip showing multiple values of a field in Altair?

Tags: tooltip, visualization, altair

I have successfully created an interactive chart as the tutorial [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_tooltip.html)  and below is my result:

[image]

I want to create a tooltip as the image below:
[image]

But I cannot find any hint in Altair tutorial document.

Can anyone provide a suggestion about how to proceed?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a single tooltip for multiple lines using the [pivot transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/pivot.html). Here is an example using one of the vega datasets.

THe idea is that the tooltip is tied to the vertical rule mark, which represents a pivoted version of the data where each relevant value is in the same row:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()
base = alt.Chart(source).encode(x='date:T')
columns = sorted(source.symbol.unique())
selection = alt.selection_single(
    fields=['date'], nearest=True, on='mouseover', empty='none', clear='mouseout'
)

lines = base.mark_line().encode(y='price:Q', color='symbol:N')
points = lines.mark_point().transform_filter(selection)

rule = base.transform_pivot(
    'symbol', value='price', groupby=['date']
).mark_rule().encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(0.3), alt.value(0)),
    tooltip=[alt.Tooltip(c, type='quantitative') for c in columns]
).add_selection(selection)

lines + points + rule
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail answer. I will follow and try it. Thank you so much ^^.